# Does it matter what the app icon shape is?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

In creation of an app icon, there is an option to customize the app icon shape to be either square, circle etc. Does it matter what the icon shape is, and is there any guide on when to use a particular shape? I have just noticed that most of the media applications on my phone have a circular shaped icon.

Comment: short answer? No. Long answer? No, it's a style thing, your app can have whatever icon shape you want on Android

Comment: Okay. This is noted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the app icon shape will be dependent on the theme or system icon settings.